# An annotation tool for aligning chunks from a sentence pairs to each other?

Tags: web-applications, annotations, data-annotations, brat

We need a tool which given two sentences, it lets the user select spans inside each sentence and align them together. 
Here is an example: 
[image]

I have been looking around for such a tool, but haven't found anything yet. Now I am thinking that I'd need to write it myself. I wonder if there are any tools our there which are close to what I want, so that it would save me some time.

Suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I created this visualization for this purpose: 
https://github.com/danyaljj/sentenceToSentenceAlignmentVisualization